# Solution of $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=\frac{x^3(t)-x^2(t)}{n}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

Consider 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) =\frac{x^3(t)-x^2(t)}{n}  \\
x(0) =x_0   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$$
$n$ is a positive constant. How to get the solution ?

I get this question from modification a proof of mean curvature flow. I have little knowledge about ODE, so I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=\frac{x^3(t)-x^2(t)}{n}$$
This ODE is separable :
$$dt=n\frac{dx}{x^3-x^2}=n\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2} \right)dx$$
$$t=n \left(\ln|x-1|-\ln|x|+\frac{1}{x}\right)+c$$
$x(0)=x_0\quad\to\quad c=-n\left(\ln|x_0-1|-\ln|x_0|+\frac{1}{x_0}\right)$

$$t(x)=n \left(\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x_0-1}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{x}{x_0}\right|+\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x_0}\right)$$

The solution of the ODE is obtained on the form of $t$ as a function of $x$.
There is no closed form for the inverse function $x(t)$. It has to be solved by numerical calculus.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know the graph of $x(t)$, what software is suitable for doing this numerical calculus ?

Comment: Any software for drawing functions is convenient. Make it draw $t(x)$.Then draw the symmetric curve relatively the line $t=x$. This gives you the curve $x(t)$.